# how to enable HTTP compression for a website which is already build and running currently in Production

Tags: performance, http, gzip, bandwidth, http-compression

how to enable HTTP compression for a website which is already build and running currently in Production

Regards,
Gourav

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in APACHE .HTACCESS (Dont know what server side are you running):

```
    # compress text, html, javascript, css, xml:
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
```

It does not matter if the site is running or not, it is .HTACCESS config.

for IIS: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771003%28WS.10%29.aspx

FOR APACHE: http://betterexplained.com/articles/how-to-optimize-your-site-with-gzip-compression/

you should test the results with firebug

Answer (score 1):

Compression is negotiated between the client and server.

The client will typically issue a request indicating that it can accept a compressed response, but doesn't have to. So you can then enable compression at the server end and your clients will receive a compressed response *only if requested*.

Check out the [Accept](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html) HTTP header.

Answer (score 1):

My favourite option is [google's pagespeed mod](http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/) for apache 2. It installs effortless on ubuntu, and presumable other linux distros.

You can see a quick list of all the features it has [here](http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/docs/filters.html).

- Extended Cache
- Puts inline CSS into external files
- Puts inline Javascript into external files
- Combine external CSS
- Move external CSS inline to the html
- Move external Javscript inline to the html
- Collapse whitespace in html
- Combine headers
- Elide attributes
- Minify Javascript
- Move small images inline
- Remove html comments
- Remove unneeded quotes from html attributes

All of the above are customizable and can be enabled/disabled as required.